# Create circular drop down in a div

Tags: html, css

I need to implement something like this:
[image]

The idea is that the menu bar contains an image or text to draw attention to the user at the right. The designer wants a circle down from the main div.

I would rather not implement the layout as an image if at all possible, or do I have to place the circle as an image inside of the div?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider using a div with rounded bottom left and bottom right border radius equal to the width of the (square) div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to align a div with radius css to create the curve.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to use an image here of some sort if it needs to be round. No content areas that I know of in html allow for a circular shape (besides using the radius border option).

You could create an img or div and position it relative to the containing main div to maintain your design.

Answer (score 0):

This will set up your rounded div without a top using only css

```
<style>
#round {
  border:4px solid;
  border-radius:50px;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border-top:none;
  border-right:none;
  border-left:none;
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
  text-align:center
}
</style>

<div id="round">Lipsum</div>
```

It would probably be nearly as small to use an svg image,

```
<svg>
    <path stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none"
          d="M 75, 0 m -75, 0 a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0 " />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="20">Lorem</text>
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="75" y="50">Ipsum</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create `circle` effect you can use

```
div {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

This way, the borders of the element will be mould and a circle shape will be created, you can use larger or smaller values for this property to make it a circle. And then place it to the right side by using:

```
div {
  float: right;
}
```